# Issue in click event using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, event-handling

I have implemented MVC application .
Code is as follow

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="mytable">
     <thead>
     <tr >  <th>  Section Name </th>
           <th>Section Code </th>
           <th> Size</th>
           <th> Avg. Length </th>
           <th style="border-right:solid #e8eef4 thick;">Thinkness</th>
           <th> Order Quantity</th>
           <th>Balance Quantity </th>
           <th style="border-right:solid #e8eef4 thick;border-left:solid #e8eef4 thick;"> Available Quantity  </th>
           <th> Supply Quantity</th>
           <th> </th>
     </tr>
    </thead>

<tbody id="tbody">

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.ProductList)

{
    <tr id="tableRow" >
        <td  > @item.SectionName</td>
        <td > @item.SectionCode </td>
        <td > @item.Size </td>
        <td > @item.Length </td>
        <td style="border-right:solid #e8eef4 thick;"> @item.Thickness </td>
        <td > @item.OrderQuantity </td>
        <td > @item.BalanceQuantity </td>
        <td  style="border-right:solid #e8eef4 thick ;border-left:solid #e8eef4 thick;" > @item.AvailableQuantity </td>
        <td ><input id="supplyQuantity" class="supply" type="text" style="width:100px ;height:15px ;margin:1px "  /></td>
        <td  id="editRow" > <a href="#" class="editClass"  style="font-size: 12px; text-decoration: none; margin-right: 10px;">Edit </a> </td>
     </tr>
}

</tbody>
</table>
```

when I click on edit link, popup should be open .In that popup window ,there should be sum of textbox values.when I clicked on `OK` button,I want to send this sum to `supply quantity` which is placed in table having `id="supplyQuantity"`.

I used Jquery ,code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.editClass').click(function () {

                $('body').append('<div id="dataConfirmModal" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" id="btnClose1"> × </button><h5 id="dataConfirmLabel">Edit </h5> </div><div class="modal-body" ><html><table style="width:530px"><tr> <th style="width:120px">Bundle Size</th><th>Count</th><th>Dispatch</th> <th> Pieces</th> </tr><tr> <td><div id="bundleSize1" >60 </div></td> <td><div  id="count1">3</div></td>  <td><input  id="dispatchValue1" type="text"  style="width:100px ;height:15px ;margin:1px" /></td> <td> <input  id="pieces1"  type="text"  style="width:100px ;height:15px ;margin:1px" disabled/></td> </tr> <tr> <td><div id="bundleSize2" >10</div></td> <td><div  id="count2">8</div></td><td><input id="dispatchValue2" type="text" style="width:100px ;height:15px ;margin:1px" /></td><td> <input   id="pieces2"  type="text"  style="width:100px ;height:15px ;margin:1px" disabled/></td> </tr> <tr style="border-bottom:solid #e8eef4 thick;"> <td><div id="bundleSize3" >1</div></td><td><div  id="count3">20</div></td><td><input id="dispatchValue3" type="text" style="width:100px ;height:15px ;margin:1px" /></td><td> <input    id="pieces3" class="txt" type="text"  style="width:100px ;height:15px ;margin:1px" disabled/></td>  </tr> <tr> <td colspan="3" style ="text-align: right; border-right:solid white;"> Total</td> <td> <input  id="total" type="text" value="0"  style="width:100px ;height:15px ;margin:1px"  disabled /></td></tr></table> </html></div> <div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" id="btnOk1"  class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >OK</button> <button type="button" id="btnCancel1"  class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >Cancel</button> </div></div> ');

                $('#dataConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
                $('#dataConfirmModal').modal({ show: true }); 

        });

        $('body').on('blur', '#dispatchValue1', function() {

            var dispatchValue = $('#dispatchValue1').val();
            var bundleSize = $('#bundleSize1').text();
            var nPieces1 = dispatchValue*bundleSize;
            $('#pieces1').val(nPieces1);

            var ntotal= $('#total').text();

            if($('#total').val() > 0)
            {
                var ntotal = $('#total').val();
                var sum=parseFloat(ntotal) +parseFloat(nPieces1);
                $('#total').val(sum);
                $('#supplyQuantity').val(sum);

            }
            else
            {
                var sum=parseFloat(nPieces1);
                $('#total').val(sum);
                $('#supplyQuantity').val(sum);

            }

        });

        $('body').on('blur', '#dispatchValue2', function() {

            var dispatchValue = $('#dispatchValue2').val();
            var bundleSize = $('#bundleSize2').text();
            var nPieces2 = dispatchValue*bundleSize
            $('#pieces2').val(nPieces2);

            if($('#total').val() > 0)
            {
                var ntotal = $('#total').val();
                var sum = parseFloat(ntotal) + parseFloat(nPieces2);
                $('#total').val(sum);
                $('#supplyQuantity').val(sum);

            }
            else
            {
                var sum = parseFloat(nPieces2);
                $('#total').val(sum);
                  $('#supplyQuantity').val(sum);
             }
        });

        $('body').on('blur', '#dispatchValue3', function() {

            var dispatchValue = $('#dispatchValue3').val();
            var bundleSize = $('#bundleSize3').text();
            var nPieces3 = dispatchValue*bundleSize
            $('#pieces3').val(nPieces3);

            if($('#total').val() > 0)
            {
                var ntotal = $('#total').val();
                var sum=parseFloat(ntotal) +parseFloat(nPieces3);
                $('#total').val(sum);
                $('#supplyQuantity').val(sum);

            }
            else
            {
                var sum=parseFloat(nPieces3);
                $('#total').val(sum);
                $('#supplyQuantity').val(sum);
             }
        });

        $('body').on('click', '#btnOk1', function() {

            var url="@Url.Action("DispatchNow")";
             $(location).attr('href', url);

         });

        $('body').on('click', '#btnCancel1', function() {

            var url="@Url.Action("DispatchNow")";
            $(location).attr('href', url);
        });

        $('body').on('click', '#btnClose1', function() {

            var url="@Url.Action("DispatchNow")";
            $(location).attr('href', url);
        });

});
```

Now,my issue is that ,when I clicked on `OK` button value from `Supply Quantity` column is getting vanished as the page is getting refresh.I want same working for remaining records also.Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You're re-using `id` values multiple times on the same page.  This is invalid markup and will likely result in undefined behavior for this code.  First use unique `id` values in your HTML elements, then debug the code again.

Comment: I don't know how to create dyanamic 'id'.Will you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following lines of code in your click functionality

```
$('body').on('click', '#btnOk1', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url="@Url.Action("DispatchNow")";
    $(location).attr('href', url);
});

$('body').on('click', '#btnCancel1', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url="@Url.Action("DispatchNow")";
    $(location).attr('href', url);
});

$('body').on('click', '#btnClose1', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url="@Url.Action("DispatchNow")";
    $(location).attr('href', url);
});
```